# Understanding $\inf(A)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $A\subset\mathbb R$ be a set.We know that $\inf(A)$ is a member of the closure of $A$. We know that $\inf(A)$ is the greatest lower bound for the set $A$.

Q1) Is it always true that $\inf(A)=\liminf{a_n}$ for some sequence $a_n$ formed by the points in $A$?

Q2) $\text {diam}(A)=\limsup|p_n-q_n|$ for two sequences of $p_n$ and $q_n$ right? So if $p_n,q_n$ does not converge, Since they are bounded and in $\mathbb R$ their subsequences converge. How do we know that their subsequences converge to $\sup$ but not $\inf$ while trying to find $\text {diam}(A)$?

Comment: Q1 is obviously true. You said that $\inf(A)$ is a member of the closure of $A$, thus it is a [limit point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point) of $A$.

Question Q2 I cannot understand

Comment: @MatiasHeikkilä: it does not have to be a limit point of $A$. If $A = \{\inf(A)\}$, then it is an isolated point of $A$.

Comment: Yes, but then you can take $x_n = \inf(A)$.

Comment: As Matias pointed out, Q1 is obviously true. About Q2, I don't understand why you work with limit superior, instead of limit: By definition, $\text{diam} A=\sup\{|p-q|: p, q\in A\}$, so there exist $(p_n)$, $(q_n)$ in $A$ such that $|p_n-q_n|\rightarrow \text{diam} A$. Any subsequence of them also has the same property. This follows immediately from the definition of a subsequence.

Comment: @MatiasHeikkilä: Yes, of course. “a member of closure $\implies$ a limit of some sequence” is true, but “a member of closure $\implies$ a limit point of the set” is not.

Comment: Also note that there may no $\inf$ or $\sup$ for unbounded sets if we are working strictly in $ℝ$, so it might be better to consider $[-∞, ∞]$ instead.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I recalled the definition of a "limit point" incorrectly. Thanks.

Comment: @treedetective I can talk about the lim if the set $A$ is compact. If it's not, that point might not be a point of convergence of a sequence. Since $A$ is not compact too I simply can't talk about a limit

Comment: @Xenidia I am not sure I am following. If a set $D\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is bounded from above, then there exists a sequence $(d_n)$ in $D$ such that $d_n\rightarrow \sup D$. This is always true, regardless of $D$ being compact or not, and it follows easily from the definition of supremum. (Similarly, if $D$ is not bounded from above then there exists a sequence $(d_n)$ in $D$ such that $d_n\rightarrow +\infty$.) In Q2 our $D$ is $D=\{|p-q|:p,q\in A\}$.

Answer (score 1):

> Let $A\subset\mathbb R$ be a set. We know that $\inf(A)$ is a member of the closure of $A$.

This is incorrect. Consider for instance $A=\mathbb{R}$. If one assumes that $A$ is *bounded*, then it would be true.

> Q1) Is it always true that $\inf(A)=\liminf{a_n}$ for some sequence $a_n$ formed by the points in $A$?

Yes, this is true by the definition of infimum. Actually, you might have 
$$
\inf(A)=\lim a_n
$$
for some sequence $a_n$ in $A$.

> Q2) $\text {diam}(A)=\limsup|p_n-q_n|$ for *some* sequences $p_n$ and $q_n$, right?

Yes. You can find the two sequences by using the definition of "$\sup$" and actually you could have
$$\text {diam}(A)=\lim|p_n-q_n|.$$

> So if $p_n,q_n$ does not converge, since they are bounded and in $\mathbb R$ their subsequences converge.

This does not make sense and it is logically wrong.

---

There seems to be some confusion about the relation between $\inf$ and $\liminf$, and the relation between $\sup$ and $\limsup$. 
Here is a simpler helpful exercise:

- Suppose $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and let $a=\inf A$, $b=\sup A$ where $a,b$ can be extended real numbers. Show that there exists sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ in $A$ such that
  $$
  \lim_na_n=a,\quad \lim_nb_n=b.
  $$

Comment: does $inf(R)$ exist?
Do you assume the set to be compact when saying$diam(A)=\lim|p_n-q_n|$

Comment: (1) Well, I'm assuming you use the extended real numbers and thus $\inf(\mathbb{R})=-\infty$. (2)No, I don't even assume that $A$ is bounded.